# How to resolve Cryptography Changes in Android P?

Tags: android, x509certificate, android-9.0-pie

First of all, I am new to this encryption operations and I don't know whether my question is proper to ask or not! any solution is appreciated ...

In my project I use this code to create SSLSocketFactory for services:

```
  public static SSLSocketFactory getGlobalSSlFactory() {
   try {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
    InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(xxxxxxx);

    Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    caInput.close();

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    keyStore.load(null, null);

    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
            KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keyStore, "xxxxxxx".toCharArray());

    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null); 
       return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return null;
  }
}
```

The error I get when testing on device with android ( Pie ) :

[image: error]

google says: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html

Important part :

"To resolve this, you should stop specifying a provider and use the default implementation."

How should I change my code ?

** more explanations **

I did what @sonhvp said but after testing that this error comes :

[image: error in log]

And error come to this line :

```
 Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
```

This is my android version :

[image: my android version]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the document said, "From Android N, we don’t recommend specifying the provider". So just remove all provider in your crypto.
In your method

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
```

remove provider ("BC")

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
```

Other methods is fine. Because it doesn't specifying a provider

```
KeyStore.getInstance("BKS"); //no provider
TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm); //no provider
KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); //no provider
SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); //no provider
```

Something is wrong with your cert file in raw folder. I created an cert file an run it with your code without any issue. Just change to `CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")`. Try with my [cert file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nAFo0-kNBk2AQYFy1-u7Cd6zIxDz1G30/view?usp=sharing)

```
public class Test {

    public Test(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        context = activity;
    }

    private Context context;

    public  SSLSocketFactory getGlobalSSlFactory() {
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);

            Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            caInput.close();

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            keyStore.load(null, null);

            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                    KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(keyStore, "xxxxxxx".toCharArray());

            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

My Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val test = Test(this)
        test.globalSSlFactory.createSocket()
    }

}
```

Comment: thx @sonhvp I've already done that but this error comes up (I added that in question)

Comment: @tahaDev, which android version are you running your app? I running your code in android P and get a different exception `java.security.cert.CertificateException: X.509 not found`. Sorry, I will check again to find a different solution.

Comment: My android is 9 same as what you have

,By the way same error I get (look at first picture I edited the question) 

thx @sonhvp

Comment: Should I create another certificate when removing provider or the old one is OK?

Comment: @tahaDev I think something is wrong with your cert file in raw folder. Since I don't have your cert file to test. Try my code and my cert file to find what wrong happened to you.

Comment: THX  I'll test it and let you kow

Comment: The certificate you sent doesn't work , is it working for you ?

Comment: It works fine with me, still getting the same error?. I will publish my sample app to Github to test it more easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195012/discussion-between-sonhvp-and-tahadev).

Comment: I did what sonhvp said and then I changed the certificate
Now it works fine
I changed the answer state as accepted @sonhvp

Comment: I’m glad that you’ve solved your problem. Happy coding!